# Can't write code in prefixr.com

Tags: css, cross-browser

Indeed i have two problems :

First, i need [prefixr.com](http://prefixr.com/) but when i open its page and i try to write my own code instead of the written example the textfield looks disable and i can't edit its content.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bc9d88;
    color: #8f6b51;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

and Second how to bypass writting code in my question when i don't need to but sof complains about not respecting its quality standards?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prefixr.com is not working. You can try this as an alternate http://simevidas.jsbin.com/gufoko/quiet